# Is there a package to process command line options in R?

Tags: r, parsing, command-line-arguments, getopt

Is there a package to process command-line options in R?

I know `commandArgs`, but it's too basic. Its result is basically the equivalent to `argc` and `argv` in `C`, but I'd need something on top of that, just like `boost::program_options` in `C++`, or `GetOptions::Long` in `perl`.

In particular, I'd like to specify in advance what options are allowed and give an error message if the user specifies something else.

The call would be like this (with user options --width=32 --file=foo.txt):

```
R --vanilla --args --width=32 --file=foo.txt < myscript.R
```

or, if `Rscript` is used:

```
myscript.R --width=32 --file=foo.txt
```

(Please don't say, "why don't you write it yourself, it's not that hard". In other languages you don't have to write it yourself either. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`getopt` for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/getopt/index.html)

Comment: Great! Too bad it's not part of the R distribution (at least not in R 2.8.1).

Answer (score 2):

How about **commandArgs** *with* **eval** for a built in solution?

**test.R**

```
## 'trailingOnly=TRUE' means only parse args after '--args'
args=(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE))

## Supply default arguments
if(length(args)==0){
    print("No arguments supplied.")
    ##supply default values
    a = 1
    b = c(1,1,1)
}else{
    for(i in 1:length(args)){
         eval(parse(text=args[[i]]))
    }
}
print(a*2)
print(b*3)
```

and to invoke it

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore '--args a=1 b=c(2,5,6)' test.R test.out
```

The usual caveats w.r.t using **eval** apply of course.

Shamelessly stolen from this [blog post](http://quantitative-ecology.blogspot.com/2007/08/including-arguments-in-r-cmd-batch-mode.html).