# Running R function as command line script with arguments

Tags: r, command-line

Lets say I have the following script

```
k <- as.numeric(readline("Start Index: "))
tot <- NULL

for (i in 1:k){
    tot <- c(tot, i)
}
write.csv(tot, "test.csv")
```

I would like to run this script from the command line. How can I run it so that it still asks for the user input (`k`). Or otherwise can I add the value of `k` in the CMD command as argument? I am on Linux.

Comment: couple of these floating around [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547789/command-line-arguments-in-bash-to-rscript), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433603/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-r-scripts), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808169/r-command-line-passing-a-filename-to-script-in-arguments-windows), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110363/is-there-a-package-to-process-command-line-options-in-r), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the information in `?commandArgs` helpful.

From the description:

```
 Provides access to a copy of the command line arguments supplied
 when this R session was invoked.
```